# MagicalRecord v2.2 and simple lightweight migration for released app

Tags: core-data, database-migration, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

I have an app in appstore and in which I had setup my magicalrecord using **setupCoreDataStack** method. I have since then versioned the data model and added an attribute to an existing entity. Now when I use **setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed** to perform lightweight migration over the released app, the debug app opens with no data.

The new version of data model is currently selected with the green tickmark in xcode and is based on the old data model. The default value for the new attribute is set. If I install released version again without deleting the debug app from the device then I see the old data, means the old data is never wiped off (which is good), it's just not shown after setting up new version of the model and performing magicalrecord lightweight migration. What am I missing here?

There is no error in debugger while loading new debug version over existing released version. The filemerge diff performed on the contents of the data model versions only show the addition of the new attribute.

Any insight into this problem or pointers will help!

Answer (score 0):

Huh, read somewhere that you can't auto-migrate if the datastore was not setup as an auto-migrate store in the first place. Someone suggested doing it over multiple releases. So assuming that was true, I tried

**[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];**

right before

**[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"XYZ"];**

and it worked.

Anyone else with same problem, no need to delete data store and create new with setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack or try manual migration. Just setup as auto-migrate store and do auto-migration one after another in the same build. Hope it works for your too!